Cannot upload 600Mb+ packages, e.g., `nvidia-cudnn` or `torch`, to `gemfury`
Uploading large packages to gemfury fails with all of the following: fury cli, curl, and web-based upload. For example, the following packages failed to upload:
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyershov dyershov 731725872 Dec 18 21:26 nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyershov dyershov 664752741 Dec 18 21:26 nvidia_cudnn_cu12-9.1.0.70-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dyershov dyershov 779141888 Dec 18 21:35 torch-2.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dyershov dyershov 779135478 Dec 18 21:35 torch-2.3.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dyershov dyershov 799097965 Dec 18 21:35 torch-2.4.0+cu121-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dyershov dyershov 906446312 Dec 18 21:35 torch-2.5.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

I get the following results with

fury cli

$ fury push --account ${FURY_ACCOUNT} --api-token ${FURY_TOKEN} --as=${MY_TEAM} --public  nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Uploading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl - Please use multipart/form-data upload (RFC-2388)                                                                                      
ERROR: Please use multipart/form-data upload (RFC-2388)

The error comes from curl and seems unrelated to fury cli.

curl

$ curl -F package=@nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl https://${FURY_TOKEN}@push.fury.io/${MY_TEAM}/

ERROR: Request too large for this endpoint.
Please use push.fury.io for large uploads:
https://gemfury.com/help/upload-packages

The output of curl is particularly puzzling because I'm already using push.fury.io endpoint.

Web-based upload instantaneously shows 100% complete, but the package is not present in the package list.

